# Erro em tempo de execução VB6

Tags: c#, .net, compilação, visual-basic-6

Estou com uma DLL que foi criado em .NET e preciso que ela rode como COM+.

código em .NET:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace thiago.dll.NET
{
    public class dllNET
    {
         public String retornoString()
         {
               return "retorno";
         }
    }
}
```

código adaptação COM+:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace thiago.dll.NET.COMPLUS
{
    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
    Guid("2382A011-76E7-4729-A8C9-A016465DCA19")]
    public interface IStringRetorno
    {
        String retornoString();
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace thiago.dll.NET.COMPLUS
{
    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    Guid("7457F910-D91C-4378-91CD-D768A32FF339")]
    public class StringRetorno : IStringRetorno
    {
        thiago.dll.NET.dllNET obj = new thiago.dll.NET.dllNET();
        public StringRetorno()
        {

        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public String retornoString()
        {
            return obj.retornoString();
        }
    }
}
```

Para explicar melhor eu fiz uma DLL em .NET e quero que ela rode em VB6, mas para isso eu precisei criar uma outra DLL(que se transformou em uma tlb que é lida em VB6) onde o VB6 consegue ver os métodos e aplica-los. O que eu percebi é que quando eu referenciei a DLL feita em .NET nessa outra DLL, ela leva o arquivo dll onde está o método, como o VB6 vai ler esta dll?

Fiz a `Strong Name Key`, marquei a opção `Register For COM interop`, referenciei no projeto a DLL feita em .NET, deixei como Assembly Global `(GAC)` e adicionei nos nos Serviços de componentes(Aplicativo de biblioteca(Aplicação COM+)), mas na hora de usar no VB6 ele dá um `Erro em tempo de execução: Erro de automação`

Tem outro modo de se fazer isto?

Edit: Eu fiz uma DLL COM+ simples, sem precisar referenciar de outra DLL .NET e quando fui jogar no VB6 funcionou. O problema pode ser a referencia na COM+ da DLL .NET?

Comment: Encontrei o erro: O problema era fazer uma DLLCOM+ para ler uma DLL.NET, sendo que, quando referenciada essa DLLCOM+ ela lavava consigo a DLL.NET e nessa o VB6 não suporte. A solução foi criar a DLL.NET e a DLLCOM+ na mesma classlibrary

Answer (score 2):

COM+ é sempre um problema...

Aqui, ao fazermos esses Wrappers, a classe COM inicial (e apenas ela) é derivada de [ServicedComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.enterpriseservices.servicedcomponent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Outras interfaces/classes obtidas a partir da inicial não precisam derivar de ServicedComponent.

Também não registramos no GAC, mas apenas usando o [RegSvcs.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04za0hca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Cuide de usar a versão 64 bits ou 32 bits conforme a máquina.

Comment: É uma solução também, mas no meu caso a minha .NET já estava criada, precisei transformar ela em COM+